# Multiple parameters to bash script

Tags: linux, unix, bash, shell-script

I need to check for user provided options in my bash script, but the options won't always be provided while calling the script. For example the possible options can be -dontbuild -donttest -dontupdate in any combination, is there a way I could check for them? Sorry if this question is real basic, I'm new to bash scripting.

Thanks

EDIT:
I tried this chunk of code out, and called the script with the option, -disableVenusBld, but it still prints out "Starting build". Am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
while [ $# -ne 0 ]
do
    arg="$1"
    case "$arg" in
        -disableVenusBld)
            disableVenusBld=true
            ;;
        -disableCopperBld)
            disableCopperBld=true
            ;;
        -disableTest)
            disableTest=true
            ;;
        -disableUpdate)
            disableUpdate=true
            ;;
        *)
            nothing="true"
            ;;
    esac
    shift
done

if [ "$disableVenusBld" != true ]; then
    echo "Starting build"
fi
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dennis had the right idea, i'd like to suggest a few minor mods.

Arguments to shell scripts are accessed by positional parameters $1, $2, $3, etc... and the current count comes in $#.  The classical check for this would be:

```
while [ $# -ne 0 ]
do
    ARG="$1"
    shift # get rid of $1, we saved in ARG already
    case "$ARG" in
    -dontbuild)
        DONTBUILD=1
        ;;
    -somethingwithaparam)
        SAVESOMEPARAM="$1"
        shift
        ;;
# ... continue
done
```

As Dennis says, if your requirements fit into getopts, you're better off using that.

Comment: What purpose does doing it this way serve? It's functionally identical to the answer I gave but has an unnecessary conditional, variable assignment and `shift` adding extra weight.

Comment: Dennis, you actually don't iterate through the arguments.  `for arg` doesn't actually work in bash, you need to reference $1, $2, etc.  You need the shift to actually iterate through the arguments, and the extra var ARG is to be able to use shift right away, so any params are in $1

Comment: `for arg` does an implicit iteration over `$@` so it most certainly *does* work. Try it. You could also do it explicitly with `for $arg in $@`. By not using `shift` you can leave `$@` intact.

Answer (score 7):

```
for arg
do
    case "$arg" in
        -dontbuild)
            do_something
            ;;
        -donttest)
            do_something
            ;;
        -dontupdate)
            do_something
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Unknown argument"
            exit 1
            ;;
     esac
done
```

Where `do_something` represents either setting a flag or actually doing something. Note that `for arg` implicitly iterates over `$@` (the array of positional parameters) and is equivalent to the explicit `for arg in $@`.

Note also that Bash has a builtin called `getopts` but it only takes short options (e.g. `-x`). There's also an external utility called `getopt` which does take long options but it has several flaws and is not recommended.

```
options=":es:w:d:"

OLDOPTIND=$OPTIND
while getopts $options option
do
  case $option in
    e     ) do_something;;
    w     ) do_something $OPTARG;;
    d     ) foo=$OPTARG;;
    q     ) do_something;;
    s ) case $OPTARG in
                m | M ) bar="abc";;
                s | S ) baz="def";;
                *     ) echo "Invalid option for blah blah" 1>&2; exit;;
        esac;;
    *     ) echo "Unimplemented option chosen.";;   # DEFAULT
  esac
OLDOPTIND=$OPTIND
done
```

Comment: The top code section doesn't compile under #!/bin/bash: "syntax error near unexpected token `case'"

Comment: @MikeBlandford: There was a missing `do` which I have fixed.